# Netlify Lambda doesn't include supporting files for Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-function

I'm using Netlify Lambda to host a form on my website.

The form worked great but it was really messy.

To clean up the file I created a new file with the necessary functions and imported them into my form file. Now I have two files instead of one. The files are `forms.js` and `formData.js`. `formData.js` has the functions that `forms.js` depends on.

For some reason, my form doesn't work now. It's like the data isn't being imported.

Here is my folder structure:

src/functions/forms/forms.js 
src/functions/forms/formData.js

`netlify.toml` file:

```sh
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  functions = "functions"
```

Inside my `forms.js` file, I have imported the data from the `formData.js` file like this:

```js
const data = require.resolve('./formData.js');
const { functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree, functionFour } = data;
```

I ran `npm run build` hoping the build would pick up the additional file, but nothing has happened and it doesn't work. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more code might help, as well as a log.

It looks like you are using [require.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) which returns a string path. You cannot destructure a string to function definitions.

Can you try `const { functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree, functionFour } = require('./formData.js');`?

Can we assume you are, in fact calling these functions somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used `require.resolve` because I saw it as one way to possibly get the data. I'm now trying `import { functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree, functionFour } from './formData';`. Yes, the functions are being called within the form file, it's just a matter of importing them from the second file (`formData`). Honestly, I should rename `formData` to `formFunctions`. Still struggling with the original problem.